# relocate postgres dump when restoring

Tags: postgresql, restore, pg-dump

Is there a way to relocate(?) a postgres dump when restoring it?

I want to restore a dump from a staging db, to my development db where the owner and schema are different from staging.

Is there another way to achieve this then doing a search and replace in the dump?

To give concrete values: my staging db has owner "iplister" and schema "public" while I want to restore to owner "developer" and schema"csapi".

Currently I do

```sh
pg_dump \
  postgresql://$OWNER:$PASSWORD@$HOST/$DB | perl -pe '
    s/[ \x27]\Kpublic\./csapi./g;
    s/\biplister\b/developer/g;
  ' > work/prod-db-$( date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S ).sql
```

To create the dump and directly search & replace.

Of course this is error-prone when the dump contains in any dataset one of the searched words. That's why I'm asking for the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution now is:

```sh
  pg_dump \
    --no-owner \
    --clean \
    --if-exists \
    postgresql://$OWNER:$PASSWORD@$HOST/$DB | perl -pe '
      if (/^(ALTER|COPY|CREATE|SELECT|DROP)/ .. /;/) {
        s/[ \x27]\Kpublic\./csapi./g;
      } elsif (/^-- /) {
        s/[ \x27]\Kpublic\./csapi./g;
      }
    '
```

The `elsif` isn't required but takes care for comments.